# How to synchronise multiple scroll controller when there are multiple single child scroll view independent of each other

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want all the rows should get scrolled together with multiple controller and without use of linked_scroll_controller.

This code snippet serves as an example. I acknowledge that the issue could be resolved by enveloping the column with a single-child scroll view instead of rows. However, the stipulation is to address this problem without utilizing that approach and linked_scroll_controller.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SynchroniseScroll extends StatelessWidget {
  SynchroniseScroll({super.key});
  final ScrollController header = ScrollController();
  final ScrollController body = ScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('DropdownFormField Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ...List.generate(
            4,
            (index) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: index == 0 ? header : body,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    ...List.generate(
                      25,
                      (index) => Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        color: index.isEven
                            ? Colors.yellowAccent
                            : Colors.purpleAccent,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Inspect the output provided below; when I scroll the row at the 2nd index, the remaining rows do not scroll in tandem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add listeners to your `ScrollControllers` and then act upon the changes reported through those listeners.
In the code below, there are listeners added to the controllers (one for each row) and in the `_handleScrollNotification` method you can see how all 3 other `ScrollControllers` are told to `jumpTo` the same location as the one that was reported by the one `ScrollController` that recorded a change:

```
class SynchroniseScroll extends StatefulWidget {
  const SynchroniseScroll({super.key});

  @override
  State<SynchroniseScroll> createState() => _SynchroniseScrollState();
}

class _SynchroniseScrollState extends State<SynchroniseScroll> {
  List<ScrollController> controllers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    controllers = List.generate(4, (index) => ScrollController());
    controllers.forEach((controller) =>
        controller.addListener((() => _handleScrollNotification(controller))));
    super.initState();
  }

  void _handleScrollNotification(ScrollController controller) {
    print(controller.position.pixels);
    controllers
        .where((element) => element != controller)
        .forEach((contr) => contr.jumpTo(controller.position.pixels));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('DropdownFormField Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: controllers
            .map((controller) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: controller,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        ...List.generate(
                          25,
                          (index) => Container(
                            height: 100,
                            width: 100,
                            color: index.isEven
                                ? Colors.yellowAccent
                                : Colors.purpleAccent,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controllers.forEach((e) => e.dispose());
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```